# How to create a footer with 3 rows? Is it possible with {scrpage2}?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

Is it possible to create a footer with 3 rows. I have already asked some people but i could not understand because i am a beginner. My knowledge regarding latex is low. Sorry. This code is just a part of a huge code. For my document i have to use following parts:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage,bibtotoc]{scrreprt} and \usepackage[automark,plainheadsepline,headsepline,footsepline,plainfootsepline]{scrpage2}
```

I hope for this packages there is a solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage,bibtotoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[automark,plainheadsepline,headsepline,footsepline,plainfootsepline]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{mwe}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead[{\includegraphics[height=14pt]{example-image-b}}]{{\includegraphics[height=14pt]{example-image-b}}}
%\ohead[\Dep]{\Dep}
%\ifoot[\jobname.pdf]{\jobname.pdf}
\ifoot[Datei:\\\jobname.pdf]{Datei:\\\jobname.pdf \\ helllooo}
\ofoot[\pagemark~ / \hspace*{0.1mm} \pageref{LastPage}]{\pagemark~ / \hspace*{0.1mm} \pageref{LastPage}}
\cfoot[\Dep]{\Dep}
\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Above you can see an example (Word 2007 Screenshot).

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** This is only a **workaround for an outdated package**.

Note that package `scrpage2` is outdated since December 2013 and option `bibtotoc` is deprecated for at least 10 years!

Workaround to keep the footer below the footsepline (assuming a onesided document):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage,
  bibtotoc% deprecated for at least 10 years, should be replaced by bibliography=totoc
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mwe}% dummy text and example images
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[
  automark,
  headsepline,plainheadsepline,
  footsepline,plainfootsepline]
{scrpage2}% deprecated since December 2013, should be replaced by scrlayer-scrpage
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead
  [{\includegraphics[height=14pt]{example-image-b}}]
  {{\includegraphics[height=14pt]{example-image-b}}}
\ifoot
  [\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}Datei:\\\jobname.pdf\end{tabular}}]
  {\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}first row\\second row\\third row\\fourth row\end{tabular}}}
\cfoot
  {first row}
\ofoot
  [\pagemark~ / \hspace*{0.1mm} \pageref{LastPage}]
  {\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{r@{}}\\second row\\\\fourth row\end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Example}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]